# Ios single xib with multiple views

Tags: ios, xib

I've noticed that i can put in a single xib multiples UIView; the main view is associated with the file's owner, but how to reference other views in the xib?

My need: i've a xib view splitted with a fixed top part and a bottom part made by a tabbar with three tab buttons: by clicking each button i need to load a subview, so my idea is to put other sub-views in the same xib on other views and load them on demand. How to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can just create `IBOutlets` in your header files and associate them with the additional views, just like any other Interface Builder component (or even just ctrl-click and drag your views to your code, if you're working in XCode's automatic assistant mode).

For example, let's say you have a view controller called `FooViewController`, and a matching `FooViewController.xib` interface file:

```
@interface FooController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *additionalView;

@end
```

...and then you can just connect your additional view up to its corresponding outlet (which will appear in IB under the file owner). It's really no different to hooking up a `UILabel` or `UIButton`.

One thing to note though - you say *"my idea is to put other sub-views in the same xib on other views and load them on demand"*. All the views inside your XIB file will actually get created at the same time, so it's not really loading on-demand. I doubt, unless you're doing something crazy, that this will be an issue for you in practice.

Comment: Hi, i can put the view in ui but buttons on this additional view are not clicking. Any advice ? @lxt